# Angular Directive for validating latitude and longitude

Tags: angular7, angular2-directives

I am working with an application which generates different kind of reports.

In couple of reports, we are using Longitude/Latitude as an input box. We need to put some validation logic for Latitude/Longitude e.g The latitude must be a number between -90 and 90 and the longitude between -180 and 180.

So what is the best-fit approach for that? Shall I create a Directive for same or any other idea?

In case of Directive if some can share some code then it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you wish to handle this... technically, HTML5 already can do that

```
<input type="number" name="longtitude" min="-180" max="180">

<input type="number" name="latitude" min="-90" max="90">
```

But you can of course use a directive, if you have more fields that you want to restrict in terms of upper and lower limits. It has several benefits while doing this. We can exert more control about how our components are used. The pure HTML5 solution has the drawback, that you can still input numbers that are greater than those.

**EDIT:** I also created a directive for you, that looks somewhat like this in the HTML Template...

```
<input #inputReference appNumberRange [inputRefObject]="{inputRef: inputReference, minValue: -180, maxValue: 180}" type="number"
            placeholder=" - Longitude- ">
```

So, what happened here? I created a directive with the name NumberRange, which has the input parameter "inputRefObject" that takes a template variable #inputReference in this case, the min and max value.

But now let's go to the directive...

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNumberRange]'
})
export class NumberRangeDirective {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() inputRefObject: {inputRef: any, minValue: number, maxValue: number};

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
  restrictNumberRange() {

    const {inputRef, minValue, maxValue} = this.inputRefObject;

    if(inputRef.value > maxValue) {
      inputRef.value = maxValue;
    } else if(inputRef.value < minValue) {
      inputRef.value = minValue
    } else {
      // Do nothing, or perhaps do something else...
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

It's kept rather simplistic and I wouldn't vouch for best practices here, but it should do what you wish it to do. 
We use the hostlistener on the object we're using the keyup event on. Technically, I wouldn't even need to pass the event in the HostListener arguments, but I left it there in case you needed it. 
But yeah, if the number is larger than the maxnumber, the value in the input is changed to the highest allowed input and vice versa for the lowest number. From there you can basically expand the way you like. You could perhaps check if the inputs are actually only of the number type! You could check the value the moment something is pasted into the input and so forth